# How to resize xfs in CentOS on GCE?

Tags: linux, centos, google-compute-engine, xfs

I have a VM with CentOS on GCE (Google Compute Engine).
I added 10GB of disk space in GCE, and the system can see this space. I tried to add 10GB to the partition with `xfs_growfs`, but it didn't work.
What went wrong? [Here's an image of the console where I tried to make the change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b59I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `growpart` first to grow the partition that XFS is sitting on, like this:

```
sudo growpart /dev/[DEVICE_ID] [PARTITION_NUMBER]
sudo xfs_growfs /dev/[DEVICE_ID][PARTITION_NUMBER]
```

This is documented pretty well in Google's official docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk).